# (Fresh VPS) Apache Default page Accessible via Telnet but not through IP address via Browser 

Tags: apache-2.2, vps

Fresh VPS. CentOS 5.5 + Apache + mysql. With root access.

I start httpd service. status running.

I type IP address from web browser. default page not being displayed.

My browser keeps showing Sending request. And ping takes 70 ms.

What could be the reason? My VPS provider couldnt solve the problem for last 5 hours.

Access Log is empty. I paste Error Log here:

```
[root@host logs]# vi error_log
[Sun Mar 04 04:28:59 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Mar 04 04:28:59 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 04 04:28:59 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Mar 04 04:28:59 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 04 04:30:22 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 04 04:53:39 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Mar 04 04:53:39 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 04 04:53:39 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Mar 04 04:53:39 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 04 04:54:16 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 04 05:05:45 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Mar 04 05:05:45 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 04 05:05:45 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Mar 04 05:05:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 04 05:25:26 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 04 05:25:26 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Mar 04 05:25:26 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Mar 04 05:25:26 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Mar 04 05:25:26 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: what does your apache error log and access log say ?

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: is there an access log as well? can we see it?

Comment: Access Log is empty

Comment: do the SIGTERMs coincide with your attempt to access the website?

Comment: @WaleedHamra just checked it no.

Comment: try this on a command line, either on an ssh session in the VPS itself, or from your home computer: 
telnet IP_Address 80

then, type the following:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: server_ip

(2 blank lines after the Host line)
apache should output the index file normally, might produce helpful errors

Comment: @WaleedHamra telnet ip_address >>> gives Name or service not known

Comment: @WaleedHamra thats before i got to type GET/HTTP..... header as you suggested.

Comment: sorry, system merged all lines to one. the command is
`telnet server_ip 80`
`GET / HTTP/1.1`
`Host: server_ip`

Comment: @WaleedHamra It shows: 501 Method Not Implemented to / not supported

Comment: hmm... how about opening telnet session as above, but typing these 2 commands: `GET /index.html HTTP/1.0` [enter] `Host: server_ip` [enter][enter]

Comment: @WaleedHamra Now shows 404 URL not found

Comment: Do you see these errors in the error log? What else gets in there?

Comment: hmm... that means apache is doing some handling properly, checking apache's default webroot for centos, i just noticed it has an "index.php" not "index.html", so you might want to try that. ie, `GET /index.php HTTP/1.0` and see what happens. if it lists the html contents of a page, then apache is working normally. if it persists, i'll be online again in 3 hours, or hopefully, someone else might help :)

Comment: @yarek error log is still the same. still, only what i pasted above.

Comment: @WaleedHamra same 404 :) it looks like i will have to try and catch u after 3 hrs ;)

Comment: perhaps, you're speaking to a transparent proxy, not to your server. Try to repeat your telnet exercises directly on the server (via a remote login session)

Comment: @yarek i am hooked on to a remote login session with complete root access.

Comment: do you get same results when telnetting `localhost` there?

Comment: @yarek in fact i just tried "GET /" (without any file name) and got CentOS standard page through telnet IP_address. now typed telnet localhost ---> unable to connect / connection refused by 127.0.0.1

Comment: @yarek wondering why its not talking to chrome. it is throwing the correct output via telnet IP_address but not via telnet localhost nor Chrome browser. something to do with httpconfig?!

Comment: you've been trying literally `telnet localhost 80`, right?

Comment: @yarek yes. now i tried telnet host_name 80. it worked correctly.

Comment: now try same telnet thing from your local machine (where the Chrome is) - any difference?

Comment: @yarek no difference

Comment: @yarek found an opposite question to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869222/why-does-a-telnet-to-port-80-seem-to-hit-a-different-server-than-firefox

Comment: @Thale would it be possible to post the IP in question?